# How to get 2 Characters after space using regex or without using regex from a string

Tags: javascript, string

I need to get intials only 2 characters after spaces, here is the sample

```
const string = "John Peter Don";
const result = string.match(/\b(\w)/g).join('');
console.log(result)// JPD->> i want only JP
```

Comment: Split with a space, get the first chars of the first two items.

Answer (score 0):

One regex approach would be to capture all leading capital letters using `match()`.  Then, slice off the first two elements and join together to form a string output.

```js
var string = "John Peter Don";
var initials = string.match(/\b[A-Z]/g).slice(0, 2).join("");
console.log(initials);
```

Comment: WIll try to use this method also

Answer (score 0):

Implementing what Wiktor Stribiżew suggested in the comments

```js
const str = "John Peter Don";
let array = str.split(" ");
console.log(array[0][0], array[1][0]);
console.log("In one string: ", array[0][0] + array[1][0]);
```

Comment: WIll try to use this method also